# Why can't I create a valid style via the mapbox api using the examples they provide?

Tags: c#, mapbox

I amp attempting to create a new mapbox style via the mapbox api. When the create process completes, I am getting a success confirmation back, but I cannot use or view the style after it is created. Based on [these docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#create-a-style) and [these docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/root), I am sending a payload to this api endpoint:

[https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/[accountname]](https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/%5Baccountname%5D)

The payload I am sending is this:

```
{
    "version": 8,
    "name": "mystyle via api",
    "sprite": "mapbox://sprites/mapbox/bright-v8",
    "metadata": null,
    "sources": {
        "mapbox-streets": {
            "type": "vector",
            "url": "mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-streets-v6"
        }
    },
    "glyphs": null,
    "layers": []
}
```

After sending this payload to the mapbox api, I receive this message back:

```
{
    "version": 8,
    "name": "mystyle via api",
    "metadata": null,
    "sources": {
        "mapbox-streets": {
            "type": "vector",
            "url": "mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-streets-v6"
        }
    },
    "sprite": "mapbox://sprites/[accountname]/ckby5s52p2r9v1hmwgkrzenvw/3teom2ial2ryn2u97lclizpce",
    "glyphs": "mapbox://fonts/[accountname]/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
    "layers": [],
    "created": "2020-06-27T21:30:49.047Z",
    "id": "ckby5s52p2r9v1hmwgkrzenvw",
    "modified": "2020-06-27T21:30:49.047Z",
    "owner": "[accountname]",
    "visibility": "private"
}
```

Then I proceed to my account in the portal and I see my new style:
[image: new style listed in my account]

However, something is wrong. The preview icon shows just a transparent graphic. And when I click on the style to view/edit it, I get this cryptic error message "Cannot read property 'mapbox:decompiler' of null":
[image]

What am I missing here? I am finding the documentation for this process very spread out through several documents. But I am copying the examples in the snippets verbatim

Answer (score 0):

This *is* a "valid" style, but it has no layers (see the last field of the JSON), that's why it doesn't display anything. (I know this is verbatim from the example in the [Create a style](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#create-a-style) docs)

The key concept here to master is the difference between [Sources](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/) and [Layers](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/). Sources are "data sources": you won't see them unless you have a Layer displaying it. Some types of Sources can contain many layers ([see the `source-layer` property in the Layer object](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#source-layer)), and/or you might want to display the same source with different stylings across different maps. That's one reason they are separated.

Or, as the Sources docs put it:

> Adding a source isn't enough to make data appear on the map because sources don't contain styling details like color or width. Layers refer to a source and give it a visual representation. This makes it possible to style the same source in different ways, like differentiating between types of roads in a highways layer.

Combining the Style object sample with the Layer object sample would give you something like this:

```
{
    "version": 8,
    "name": "mystyle via api",
    "sprite": "mapbox://sprites/mapbox/bright-v8",
    "metadata": null,
    "sources": {
        "mapbox-streets": {
            "type": "vector",
            "url": "mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-streets-v6"
        }
    },
    "glyphs": null,
    "layers": [
        {
            "id": "water",
            "source": "mapbox-streets",
            "source-layer": "water",
            "type": "fill",
            "paint": {
            "fill-color": "#00ffff"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, keep in mind that the [global Mapbox styles](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#mapbox-styles) contain several layers (maybe up to a couple dozen), with very fine settings such as what type of features should show at which zoom level and with what configurations, etc. Most applications should not need to recreate those from scratch.

If you want to overlay dynamic data (to be decided at runtime), you can use one of the global styles and [dynamically add a Layer](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#addlayer) on top of an untouched default style. The link is for Mapbox GL JS, assuming the UI is browser-based. If the UI is a mobile app, there are corresponding methods in the iOS and Android SDKs.

Now, if you don't need dynamic data at all, consider [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/) instead. This will allow you to create a custom style (with the default styles as templates if you want) and add/remove layers. For example, if `mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11` is *almost* a perfect fit, but you don't need to (say) show small town names, you can create a custom template in Mapbox Studio and remove just that. In the end, it will you give you a style ID which you can just put into your map like a default (global) style.

Also note that, depending on your case, you may combine both approaches.

Comment: Thanks Rafael, this helps. And that makes sense. It sounds like it will be tedious to recreate something equivalent to the "Basic Template" from scratch. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: Also, just to give you some background (and my reasoning for going this route) - I am attempting to create maps that have geojson data overlaid on top. I do understand that I can do this from the client side dynamically. But the geojson files that I have are very complex, and when overlaying them from the client side, the maps become very laggy and un-responsive. My thought was to create "pre-rendered" maps with the geojson data overlaid. I need around 500 separate combinations of geojson data, so I would need 500 separate maps. That's why I am trying to create them programmatically.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is correct, recreating the basemap would be unadvisable. If the GeoJSON set does not change (often, at least), you may consider creating a custom map on Mapbox Studio with all 500 of them in separate layers, and then, at runtime, adding a new source and layer(s) pointing what you want to display. [This Mapbox example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/vector-source/) does just that - uses `light-v10` as a base style, untouched, and adds `mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2` as a separate source with a layer pointing to it. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) In your case, you would replace `mapbox.mapbox-terrain-v2` with your custom source ID from your custom Mapbox Studio map. If you don't want to use Mapbox Studio, another option would be to create a vector tileset with them using [Tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe).

Comment: Thanks Rafael, that's a great idea, and in fact I tried that initially. I created a map in Mapbox Studio, and added 3 of the geojson files as a test, each as a separate layer. And then when I load that style/map in my browser, all three layers are shown automatically, without me specifically telling the map component to show them, and I can't turn individual ones off. This would be the ideal solution if I can get it to work. I'm probably doing something wrong in the studio editor. Is there a certain way I need to add my geojson files in MB Studio in order to make them "toggle-able"?

Comment: I would _think_ you could keep the `style` of your basic map the global one and adding the style ID of the separate MB Studio style as a _source_, but I'm not sure. You could create one [Tileset](https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/reference/tilesets/) for each source GeoJSON as well (no need for combinations, you can toggle them separately). Those can be added [to a Mapbox GL map](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/vector-source/), directly. Self-cutting and self-hosting your vector tiles with Tippecanoe would still be an option as well.